# Maven install external jar through pom not working

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I want to add a an external jar to my project. I want to add it inside the pom instead of installing it via the maven command.

This is what I have configured inside my pom:

```
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5</version>
          <executions>
              <execution>
                  <phase>install</phase>
                  <goals>
                      <goal>install-file</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <configuration>
                      <repositoryLayout>default</repositoryLayout>
                      <groupId>org.opencv</groupId>
                      <artifactId>opencv</artifactId>
                      <version>3.2.0</version>
                      <packaging>jar</packaging>
                      <file>${project.basedir}/../runtime-resources/opencv-dep/opencv-320.jar</file>
                      <generatePom>true</generatePom>
                  </configuration>
              </execution>
          </executions>
      </plugin>
  </plugins>
```

I'm getting this error:
`The POM for org.opencv:opencv:jar:3.2.0 is missing, no dependency information available.`

But when running the command, everything is oke:
`mvn install:install-file -Dfile={absolute-path-to-jar}/opencv-320.jar -DgroupId=org.opencv
-DartifactId=opencv -Dversion=3.2.0 -Dpackaging=jar`

NOTE: This is only the case on **Netbeans** and not on **InteliJ**. Netbeans apparently skips the install command and just searches for the dependency online, and ofcourse can't find it. I ran `mvn install` `mvn install:install` `mvn install:install-file`

Comment: Install that jar into a repository manager and use it as usual dependency.

Comment: Is it the filename? Is it looking for 3.2.0 rather than 320?

Comment: @khmarbaise never did that. I'll look into it after work.

Comment: @Justin.Cooke the file name is indeed opencv-320.jar

Comment: @Yoshua.Nahar I mean have you tried changing it to 3.2.0? Just in case, maven has a convention in jar names etc.

Comment: Nope, I have not. I tried running my project in InteliJ and it just works... It seems inside Netbeans, right click on project -> run goal `clean install`, is causing this error.

Comment: I am getting this tho. But InteliJ is cool without the pom. I'll check whats up with Netbeans on monday. `[INFO] pom.xml not found in opencv-320.jar
[INFO] Installing ~/Documents/IdeaProjects/face/opencv-320.jar to ~/.m2/repository/org/opencv/opencv/3.2.0/opencv-3.2.0.jar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from this question: [Maven Install plugin: parameter file is missing or invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26560555/maven-install-plugin-parameter-file-is-missing-or-invalid)

Change `<phase>install</phase>` to `<phase>initialize</phase>` and run with `mvn initialize`. And it solved my problem on Netbeans.